# MIPS Assembly Number of Instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.text  
.global main  
main:      
        addi    $v0, $zero,0  
        la  $t0, length  
        lw  $t1, 0($t0)  
        la  $t4, array  
        addi $t1, $t1, -1  
        sll $t1,$t1,2  

loop:   
        add $t3, $t4,$t1  
        lw  $t2,0($t3)  
        add $v0,$v0,$t2  
        addi $t1,$t1,-4  
test:   
        slti $t9,$t1,0  
        beq $t9,$zero,loop  
        nop   
        sw  $v0, 0($t0)  
.data  
length: .word 8  
array:  .word 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2
```

I have to tell how many static instructions are in this code. I know that before data there are 16 instructions, I am wondering if the directives written after .data are also considered as 2 instructions, making a total of 18 instructions.

Comment: No, directives are not instructions.

Comment: But you'd probably need to know the base address of the data segment to be able tell the instruction count, since that determines how many instructions `la` will translate into.

Comment: That's why i'm wondering if length is somehow loaded into memory or not, and if it count as an instruction. So, looking at this code you can confirm is written in 16 static instructions?

Comment: No, for that I would need to know where in memory the data segment is located. If e.g. the data segment starts at `0x10000000` you could translate `la $t0,length` into a single instruction (`lui $t0,0x1000`), but if it starts at e.g. `0x10001000` that same `la` would require two instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Yesno.

The directive "`.data`" itself doesn't compile into anything machine related, it only marks another section of source, which with some toolchains will lead into linking that part of compiled source in different linking stage, possible landing into specific executable part (noted by headers of executable, depends on target platform executables format).

And those `.word 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2` do compile as word-sized numerical values 9, 8, ...

But from the CPU point of view numbers in memory are as good as instructions, so would you try to execute it, the CPU would happily hop on it, and execute those numbers as instructions (of garbage meaning, probably crashing machine). IIRC MIPS is risc-like with fixed instruction size to single word, so the line `.word 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2` contains 8 instructions.

But you have to tell, how many instructions were *executed*. And that does depend on the flow of execution of the code. In your case the code looks quite simple and straightforward till the end, with simple loop (should you count the instructions several times or just once, per loop?).

Where it ends with `sw  $v0, 0($t0)` instruction. That's store word? So CPU will follow on next instruction (next word value in memory). What is there is not defined in the source, if the `.data` segment starts there, then words 8, 9, 8, ... will be executed as instructions (too lazy to disassemble that, what it would turn into).

So the reasonably human-readable source has 16 instructions, which I would be afraid to execute on the HW, as the code looks unfinished.

And... where did you count 16 instructions? I see 14 only?

---

Would be probably easier to check disassembly, as Michael pointed out some loads may assemble into several opcodes, depending on the immediate value.

Comment: _"I see 14 only"_ `la` is a pseudo-instruction and doesn't necessarily translate into one actual instruction.

Comment: la is translated into lui and ori

Comment: The real question is shown in the Original Post, how many static instructions are in this code 16 or 18? Because I dont know if lenght : .word 8 and array: .word 9,x1,x2...xn are counted as instructions or not.

Comment: @SebastianC no, your question is "executed". And the code is not valid AFAIK, so it's not clear, where the execution will terminate, and where you should stop counting. Would the code properly exit, the `.data` section would be intentionally off-limit, and not countable. Also when .data section would execute in this case (because of bug in the code not exiting back to caller), it would add not two, but 9 possible instructions (how many of them would really execute depends on their disassembly). ... But normally you don't execute data, so usually data are count as binary data, not instructions.

Comment: Point of my answer is, that the CPU doesn't care... whatever "word" (value in memory) it encounters on $pc, it will execute it. Where that pattern of instruction leads/loops/branches, it's up to the programmer. If you execute data by accident, CPU will merrily execute them as instruction opcodes, with whatever consequences it will have. There's no difference between instructions and data in memory and you can't tell them apart (although some educated guess is usually successful, as data rarely form anything sensible in terms of instructions). @SebastianC

Comment: @SebastianC been thinking about it. In your question it looks like you think the `.word` may form the instruction too. But it's the `8` which produces the instruction! The `.word` is just assembler directive with no instruction. So those two lines in `.data` either shouldn't be count, or they form 9 additional instructions, because the data are 9 words big, and 1 word = 1 instruction. Whether the correct answer is 16 or 25 is hard to tell, probably neither would be true on real HW, as the execution would go wild after last line of code and I doubt the .data would be linked right after .text.